# Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel, or one of its dependencies. Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: c#, wcf

The full message is

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, or
>   one of its dependencies. **Not enough storage is available** to process
>   this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Was running the program on .net framework 4.5 and on a windows 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several similar posts but none point to the problem in my case.

By removing the call to the WCF i found out that was a memory problem. 
The process consumed more memory than the process memory limit for a windows 32b system.

The message part `Not enough storage` was the difference i found from errors on other posts.